# Solc: Build from source code failed. Error: ‘mod’ is not a member of ‘z3’

Tags: solidity, solc, build-from-source

I tried to build solidity compiler (solc) from source code, which was cloned from [Solidity Git Repository](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity). I followed the instructions in [Solidity Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html), but I ran into an error when execute: `cmake .. && make`. The cmake error is as follows:

```
[ 42%] Building CXX object libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/formal/Z3Interface.cpp.o
/my/path/to/solidity/libsolidity/formal/Z3Interface.cpp: In member function ‘z3::expr dev::solidity::smt::Z3Interface::toZ3Expr(const dev::solidity::smt::Expression&)’:
/my/path/to/solidity/libsolidity/formal/Z3Interface.cpp:166:14: error: ‘mod’ is not a member of ‘z3’
   return z3::mod(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
              ^~~
/my/path/to/solidity/libsolidity/formal/Z3Interface.cpp:166:14: note: suggested alternative: ‘cond’
   return z3::mod(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
              ^~~
              cond
libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/build.make:1166: recipe for target 'libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/formal/Z3Interface.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/formal/Z3Interface.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:389: recipe for target 'libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libsolidity/CMakeFiles/solidity.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed z3 prover with pre-built binaries (version 4.8.4 - 64 bit - build hashcode d6df51951f4c) provided [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases) and z3/bin has been included in my PATH variable.

I was using Ubuntu 18.04.

Did I install z3 in a wrong way? [Solidity Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html) mentions that z3 is optional, so I don't think this error is related to my z3 installation.

Can anybody help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause after opening an issue [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/6436). I have multiple Z3 versions and cmake is confused.